# Selenium ChromeDriver (C#) Crashes Only in Visual Studio Debug Mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing an issue running my Selenium tests written in C# in Visual Studio.

The issue I have is when I run the tests on ChromeDriver  from the studio in debug mode, the chrome window always crashes with a frowny face.

[image]

The chromedriver command window shows the following error in a loop (~20 times).

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf) on port 52376
Only local connections are allowed.
[28356:19528:0922/134628:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(528)] Failed to launch child process
```

This is the trace I get:

```
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)

at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)

at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)

at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)

at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)

at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)

at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options)
```

The best part is that when I run the test directly from the explorer (outside the studio), it works just fine.

I use a test runner built by someone else. I am not sure what the runner is using.

> **IDE:** Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 3
>
> **Chrome Driver Version:** 2.24.417431

**Bottomline:** I want to be able to run my Selenium tests from the Studio (in debug mode) itself. Can anyone please help me out here?

Comment: I kinda found a work-around for this.
I had setup Visual Studio to always run at Administrator level.
It works without problems when I set it to run as a normal user (non-admin mode). 

No definitive solution yet though.

Comment: Ever find anything about this? I have the opposite problem..

Comment: Nope, nothing yet. I've continued to run as a non admin for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have observed that if chrome driver version is not compatible with chrome browser version, chrome driver (before V2.28) is throwing errors while manipulating the browser (i.e. Maximize, resize etc.)

Solution 1:
Use [Version 2.28](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) as it has fixed a bug which blocked ChromeDriver automation extension from loading and thereby causing window resizing/positioning & screenshot functionalities to break. (Note that ChromeDriver 2.28 supports Chrome v55-57)

Solution 2:
If your chrome driver is not updated to V2.28: Use appropriate [Chromium Command Line Switch](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) (ex. `chromeOptions.AddArguments("--start-maximized");`) to manipulate the browser and remove the line `driver.manage().window().maximize();` if any.

Mark +1 if this answer is useful to you.