# C# Selenium ChromeDriver: Failed to launch child process

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Problem: Chrome driver doesn't work for me.
I'm using C# in Visual Studio and Selenium 3.2.0.

Code I use:

```
    string driverPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\x32";
    driver = new ChromeDriver(driverPath);
```

What happens:
Chrome launches, but on the tab I have sad face, and the grey area in a window.
In console I see following error:

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.27.440174 on port 30235 Only local connections
>   are allowed. ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc<522> Failed to launch
>   child process

The last one is repeated a couple of times.
Did anyone face such an issue in the past?

Comment: Please check this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645918/selenium-chromedriver-c-crashes-only-in-visual-studio-debug-mode

Comment: I did it both ways running as administrator and normal user. In all cases I had the same result, same error.